# how to prove that the topology generated by the left-closed intervals is finer than the usual topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-writing, problem-solving, sorgenfrey-line

The idea is to prove that the open intervals (like $]a,b[$) are contained in the topology of the left-closed sets ($[a,b[$), but I cannot see a way of generating open sets from half-closed sets. (Same goes for the right-closed sets)

Answer (score 2):

$ ]a,b[ = \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} [a + \frac{1}{n},b[$

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1866967)

Comment: @Leucippus This is exactly the answer I would expect. It doesn't require any clarification.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Note that the sequence $\frac1n\to 0$, but $0\notin\{\frac1n:n\in\mathbb N\}$.

Can you think of a way to use this with a family of intervals to prove what you want?